# Removing a weird file from git repository on mac

Tags: xcode, git, terminal, repository, openears

I recently tried adding the OpenEars framework to my xcode project, and when I tried to commit my project to the repository I get the following error:

> error: pathspec '"Framework/Icon\r"' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I have tried to find this file using the navigation tree within xcode but it doesn't exist. There is a physical file on the disk which was 0 bytes (this is most likely the problem), and I tried removing this with no affect.

I tried to navigate to the file using terminal and use git rm Icon\r but due to the \ in the name it cannot find the file:

```
$ git rm Icon\\r
fatal: pathspec 'Framework/OpenEars.framework/Icon\r' did not match any files
```

Has anyone had a similar issue or know how I can remove this file as it is stopping me from pushing any changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove weird 'Iconr' file from the repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589978/remove-weird-iconr-file-from-the-repository)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `cd`ing into the directory, then start typing the following until you get to the `I` in `Icon\r`. Then press the Tab key to have the Terminal automatically complete the rest of the path. It will look like this:

`git rm Framework/OpenEars.framework/Icon^M`

NB: There is a space after the M. Entering in this full path does not seem to work: only allowing the Terminal to autocomplete the path for you will.

I got:

```
MacPro:OpenEarsDistribution mdouma46$ git rm Framework/OpenEars.framework/Icon^M 
'm 'Framework/OpenEars.framework/Icon
MacPro:OpenEarsDistribution mdouma46$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    "Framework/OpenEars.framework/Icon\r"
#
```

Comment: Hmm, must have to do with the git export flattening the framework's icon. I'll look into it for the next version.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked for me after some alterations. I forgot the space the first time and this entered in to a second console thing which seemed to remove the reference but didn't register the removal on xcode. So I had to delete the whole framework and re-add it, this created a fresh file for me to remove properly.
Thanks once again!

Comment: I'd advise users to make a copy of the problematic file before removal.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue, and found that after removing the file from the local filesystem, the following worked for me:

```
cd Your/Project/Directory
git add -u Path/To/Offending/File/Icon$'r'
```

This then allowed me to commit and remove the files from the git repository.