# Git pathspec error: Iconr did not mach any files

Tags: xcode, macos, git, osx-mavericks

I have tried to commit my project in Xcode. But it gives me this error:

> error: pathspec 'RGZH/Pixate/Iconr' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I have seen this question: [Removing a weird file from git repository on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786037/removing-a-weird-file-from-git-repository-on-mac)

Tried it but gave me the same error. Iconr is also exactly the same like in that question except for the backslash. (Does not exist in Finder, but I can cd in via Terminal)

I need this because without the Bots don't work.

Btw. OSX Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.2.

Comment: Suggested work-around in this question worked for me in a similar scenario (`Icon\r` file): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589978/remove-weird-iconr-file-from-staging